# Difference between using GetterUtils and ParamUtils

Tags: api, methods, liferay

For instance, when to use

```
GetterUtil.getBoolean()
```

and when

```
ParamUtil.getBoolean()?
```

Are both same, or is it expected to be used differently according to a parameter, a variable, etc? Can you give some examples for both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are util methods to avoid [Null-Pointer Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/468763).

[`GetterUtil`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/src-html/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/GetterUtil.html) internally returns the default type and does the casting too. So in case where someone has passed a `null` value, it will return default value of the type.

Example:
Assume you have a `String` value `"true"`, and you are expecting it will always be of type `boolean`. So you use `GetterUtil.getBoolean("true")` which will internally do the casting to boolen and return the value as `boolean-true`. Incase someone passes rubbish characters like `"tr"`, it will be converted to `boolean-false`.

As mentioned [`ParamUtil`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/src-html/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/ParamUtil.html) does the same treatment with `request` parameters. [`ParamUtil`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/src-html/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/ParamUtil.html) internally uses the [`GetterUtil`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/src-html/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/GetterUtil.html) to have the above behaviour. It first retrieves the parameter (which always would be a string) and then passes it to `GetterUtil.getType()` method and in turn returns the proper type.

Answer (score 2):

GetterUtil and ParmUtil both are different classes.

GetterUtil is to get the default values for basic Java data types.

ParamUtil is to retrive the values(of primitive data types) from the HttpReqeust.

Check the source code here for these two classes here

For GetterUtil
http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/src-html/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/GetterUtil.html

For ParamUtil
http://docs.liferay.com/portal/5.1/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/ParamUtil.java.html

Comment: GetterUtil.getBoolean will return the default value of the boolean variable which is false.  ParamUtil.getBoolean will take the HttpRequest and Parameter name and will return the corresponding boolean value.